# How to Retrieve a Saved Password from Cyberduck bookmark?

Tags: windows, cyberduck

I'm able to access the host server via the Cyberduck bookmark. However, is there a way to retrieve the saved password in this case?

[**This**](http://www.cocoaforge.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=21457) seems to suggest there is a thing called `keychain`, but where do I access it from? The answer there says "Application/Utilies", but I don't see a menu field named "Application" in Cyberduck.

Comment: That article talks about MacOSX systems, where you can retrieve the password from KeyChain -&gt; Password -&gt; &lt;IPhost&gt; -&gt; "Show password".

Comment: @mginius So there is not Windows-based approach?

Answer (score 0):

In windows version of cyberduck, passwords are stored in Windows Credential Manager (Under windows credentials).

[https://docs.cyberduck.io/cyberduck/bookmarks/#passwords][1]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into this problem except that I didn't want to retrieve the password, I just wanted to remove it from Cyberduck's store. As far as I found there's no way to retrieve the password as it's encrypted in the file I'll be talking about with DPAPI. Anyway, I was able to delete the stored password:

1. Close Cyberduck.
2. Find the `user.config` file by:

   > opening a File Explorer window and past[ing] %APPDATA%/iterate_GmbH in the Quick access location field
   >   then opening the "Cyberduck..." folder and opening user.config in a text editor.
3. Find the tag that refers to your username for the server for which you want to delete the password. Delete the entire tag.

When you open Cyberduck again, the password shouldn't show up when you type your username on that server. I hope this helps someone.

Sources:
https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/9096
https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/faq#Preferencesandapplicationsupportfileslocation